# what is the best schema for this database scenario?

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

i have a database scenario that there is a product and user and market and all of this have a image and the image have name , alt , description so what is the best structure for the database schema

1. making only one table for image and reference product and user and market to it
2. make a images table for each module like Product_images , user_images , Market_images and so on

thanks in advance

Comment: If the only difference between each module image is the module type (product/user/etc) then you should use one table with additional column to specify the type.

Comment: thank you for your comment , but let's say that the one product have more than one image , this will not effect on the performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product, User, Market and Image table will be the good choice.

Image id will be mapped to respective table like product, user and market.

All the image attributes should be kept in image table

Comment: thank you for your comment , but let's say that the one product have more than one image , this will not effect on the performance ?

Comment: In this case create bridge table for image and other table and use flag (like P, U, M) in that bridge table

Comment: thank you very much , but did you have any idea how to implement this schema in sequelize.js ?